# Why self-referential struct in C output is nill

Tags: c, pointers, self-reference, construct

I want to create a structure in C and I want it to have only one component which will be its address.

In other words I just create a one component self-referential struct:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
 
struct Books {
   struct Books *ptr; //* the only one component of this structure*//
};

int main( ) {
    struct Books book1;
    printf("%p\n", book1.ptr);
    
    return 0;
}
```

The output of this script is - nil.

And my question is - why ? This script has created in computer memory physical entry where the one component struct- book1 is recorded.

Now I want to see the address of this struct (or to say in different words I want to see content of this one-component struct).

Once it physically exists why does it give me output nill ?

Comment: the nil is undefined behaviour, it just happens that the memory for book1 is nil. To get the behaviour you expect you'd have to do ``book1.ptr=&book1``

Comment: You never initialized the `book1.ptr`, therefore it's content is indeterminate.

Comment: `struct Books book1; book1.ptr = &book1;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:`printf("%p\n", &book1);` for printing the address of the struct.
You are trying to print out an uninitialized value and the programm has undefined behavior.
**Use & to print addresses**

Comment: You can actually be a bit more flexible and use `&book1.ptr` regardless whether `ptr` is initialized as the address for `book1` and the address of `book1.ptr` are the same.

Answer (score 4):

If you want a structure member (or any object) to have a particular value, you must initialize or assign it to have that value. Just because the type of the member is “pointer to `struct Books`” does not mean it points to the  `struct Books` it is in or that it has any other particular value.

Use `struct Books book1 = { &book1 };`.

Also, the `%p` conversion for `printf` should be given a `void *` argument, so cast the address you are passing: `printf("%p\n", (void *) book1.ptr);`.